# Validation in my registration form is not working

Tags: php

I have created a simple registration form in php using PDO to store in backend. When I entered space bar it will take as empty fields in backend and if I didn't enter anything it doesn't show any error message.

```
<?php
session_start();
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
// configuration
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "pdo_ret";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];

if($fname == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your First Name';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($lname == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Last Name';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($age == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Age';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}
// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO members (fname,lname,age) VALUES (:sas,:asas,:asafs)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':sas'=>$fname,':asas'=>$lname,':asafs'=>$age));
header("location: index.php");
 ?>
```

Comment: It's not relevant to PDO. Space bar is a whitespace then `'' !== ' '`. You might want to `trim()` ?

Comment: What is your problem / question ? You're just saying things.

Comment: @RoyalBg: I googled related to PDO and get this code from google. and i want to create registeration form by using PDO.and i m new to PDO can you help?

Comment: @selva You gave us the current behavior, but what is the WANTED behavior ?

Comment: @RoyalBg told, this is not PDO relevant, but i thought this is PDO relevant and i m new to PDO.so i need to create register form using PDO in php

Comment: "it doesn't show any error message" - are you saying that it doesn't populate the session variable?

Comment: @selva it's not showing the error even before reach the query, isn't it common sense that you are not capturing the error far before execute the query, so two things are not related ?! Even if you do not have any connection to db, it will not show errors for whitespaces, because you are checking for empty string, but `'   '` is not equal to `''`

Comment: @RoyalBg: first of all., i want to know posted code above is PDO relevant or not?

Comment: The whole code is - it's trying to execute a mysql query via PDO. The problems you are having, are not related to PDO, they are completely irrelevant. You will have the same problems if you start your code with this line `$fname = $_POST['fname'];` and end until this line `exit();
}`. Why don't you try to learn the language constructs and concepts before trying to modify a foreign code into working state? You should be at least aware if you code is related to something or not.

Comment: @RoyalBg: it doesn't show any error, but when the fields are empty it should shows error message.

Comment: @selva for third time I will tell you that you cannot expect error messages when user enters spaces into the input fields, when you are comparing `''` to `' '` ...

Comment: @RoyalBg:sorry for my mistake.. can you tell me any relevant link to create form using PDO in php?

Comment: Your code is fair enough to create code using PDO, you additional checks for empty strings and so on, are not related to PDO, I would suggest just to learn how does `empty()` and `trim()` behave :)

Answer (score 1):

If string with whitespace only is a wrong one, you should use [`trim`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.trim.php) function:

```
if(trim($fname) == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your First Name';
    $errflag = true;
}
if(trim($lname) == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Last Name';
    $errflag = true;
}
if(trim($age) == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Age';
    $errflag = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use trim function but not in conditions but when assigning $_POST data

Instead of:

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
```

you should have code:

```
$fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
$lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
$age = trim($_POST['age']);
```

Otherwise you will put data into database with possible white characters and it cause problems in future.